Problem with an example in Werner Amrein book
There is something I don't understand in example 4.13 of Werner Amrein's book "Hilbert Space Methods in Quantum Mechanics".
Just before equation (4.55) he says that:

if $\lambda\in\text{supp}\left\{E_{\lambda}\right\}$, one has $||(A-\lambda-i\epsilon)^{-1}||=1/|\epsilon|$, which shows that $\text{supp}\left\{E_{\lambda}\right\}\not\subseteq\rho(A)$

I don't know how to prove $||(A-\lambda-i\epsilon)^{-1}||=1/|\epsilon|$ and I don't understand how this implies that $\text{supp}\left\{E_{\lambda}\right\}\not\subseteq\rho(A)$.
In all this, $A$ is a self-adjoint operator with spectral family $\left\{E_{\lambda}\right\}$. $\text{supp}\left\{E_{\lambda}\right\}$ is the support of the spectral family, $\rho(A)$ is the resolvent of $A$, and $\epsilon>0$.
I have tried to use that
$$||(A-\lambda-i\epsilon)^{-1}||=||\int_{\infty}^{\infty}(\kappa-\lambda-i\epsilon)^{-1} E(d\kappa)||=\text{sup}_{x\in\text{supp(E)}}|x-\lambda-i\epsilon|^{-1}$$
but I don't get the answer.
Another question, is there any alternative book or books where I could find these kind of results with a better explanation? I have read another references like Reed and Simon or Joachim Weidmann, but none of them have this kind of "little" facts, and I am studying the topic by myself.
I have had problems understanding another little steps in this same book, in a similar way like this one, and that slows my study.

Do you mean $|(A-\lambda-i\epsilon)^{-1}|$?

Robert Israel Yeap, Thank you for the correction. I apologize for the mistake.

Hint for the first: You presumably know that $\operatorname{supp} (E) \subset \mathbb{R}$.
Hint for the second:
The resolvent map $\rho(A) \ni z \mapsto (A-z)^{-1}$ and the operator norm are continuous.
To your third question: The fact that the support of the spectral family is equal to the spectrum of the operator is proven in any book that covers the topic (although usually in the form of spectral measures). Another book that discusses spectral families (and a lot of other interesting things about self-adjoint operators) in detail is Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space by Schmüdgen.
